# Out of bounds for length Exception

Tags: java, arrays

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, mayor=0, menor=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingresar la cantidad de edades que se van a ingresar");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();
        int edades[] = new int[n];

        for (i = 0; i < edades.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese la primer edad en la posicion " + (i+1) + " del arreglo");
            edades[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < edades.length; y++){
            if(edades[i] > mayor){
                mayor = edades[i];
            }
            if(edades[i] < menor){
                menor = edades[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El mayor valor ingresado es "+mayor);
        System.out.println("El menor valor ingresado es "+menor);
    }
}
```

I think that I did everything right, But I get the error " out of bounds for length".

Sorry for the Spanish, that's my primary language.

Comment: Please revise your question's tags.  4 out of 5 are irrelevant ... or clearly misleading.  For example, you are not programming in `[typescript]`.  If you are unsure about whether a tag relates to your question, read the tag wiki.

Comment: @OleV.V. If you're going to fix the title, please *fix* it.  It doesn't need to be a god title; a diablo title might work.

Comment: @AmrDeveloper Please note that the T comes before the H in the word "length"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you used the variable `i` from the last loop in the new loop

```java
for(int y = 0; y < edades.length; y++){
    if(edades[i] > mayor){
        mayor = edades[i];
    }
    if(edades[i] < menor){
        menor = edades[i];
    }
}
```

If `n` is equal to 10 for example so after the first loop that variable `i` will have the value 10 and exit the loop, in the next loop you try to access the slot with index n and this is out of index because array indexes are from 0 to n - 1, so the right code will be

```java
for(int y = 0; y < edades.length; y++){
    if(edades[y] > mayor){
        mayor = edades[y];
    }
    if(edades[y] < menor){
        menor = edades[y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this for loop

```
 for(int y = 0; y < edades.length; y++){
            if(edades[i] > mayor){
                mayor = edades[i];
            }
            if(edades[i] < menor){
                menor = edades[i];
            }
        }
```

**You are running a for loop with the variable y but using only variable i inside the loop**, as because of the previous loop the i variable is post incremented so after the loop ends (the condition is met) **the i variable is possibly equal to edades.length which is out of bounds** for edades as it's index starts from 0 to edades.length -1 , try changin the i with j in the above for loop.

Hopefully this solves your problem. :)